# Distinct DateTime field without Time in HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I'm trying to select Distinct DateTime field in HQL.

```
select distinct CreatedDate from ClaimFile order by CreatedDate DESC
```

Any Idea how can I get distinct dates without time. right now it can't be distinct with time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of a couple of options:

1. Register a `CustomSQLFunction` in your dialect and use that to format 
   the DateTime into a Date.
2. Create a ComputedColumn (sql server) which just strips off the Time. Add it to the mapping as a read only and use that.
3. Just fall back to plain SQL since you only seem to need a list of Dates and not objects.
4. Use a `formula` in a `property` mapping. [Property Mapping Element Explained](http://ayende.com/blog/3936/nhibernate-mapping-property)
   `<property name="CreateDate" formula="cast(convert(varchar(10),CreateDate,103) as datetime)" />`.

Comment: Can you please send me an example like how can I register Convert sql function in Dialect

Comment: Here are a couple of links to get you started: http://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/registering-freetext-or-contains-functions-into-a-nhibernate-dialect.aspx

Comment: Also bear in mind that using SQL Functions will serialise the query and considerably hurt query performance.